# Removing User Profiles via UserProfileService

Tags: sharepoint, service, profile

I can't seem to find an asmx that has a "Remove" User Profile method...the
UserProfileService has Create and Modify, but no Remove...where should I be
looking to programattically remove a user profile via an WSS WebService?

Please advise.

Answer (score 1):

You appear to be correct:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/websvcuserprofileservice.userprofileservice_methods.aspx
You would however be able to do this from code that uses the server object model.

Answer (score 1):

There is no out of the box web service to delete/remove profiles. We had to create a custom web service deployed to the 12/ISAPI folder (where the OOTB web services are), that took a username as a parameter and called the sharepoint API to then remove the profile.